# Extra spaces appearing in Ansible templates

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am generating config files and I want them to be indented just so. I started with a Jinja2 template that rendered correctly when called from a simple python program. When I call it from ansible, I will get 2 extra spaces on all but the first line of the loop. Generating things like YAML and python has been a real pain. I have taken to putting a comment line as the first line of a for block to fix this...

Here is a really simple example of a YAML generator:

playbook call:

```
  - name: generate bgp vars file, put in includes directory
    local_action: template src={{ role_dir }}/templates/bgp_vars.j2 dest={{ incvar_dir }}/bgp_vars.yaml
    run_once: true
```

section of template:

```
dc_route_reflectors:
{% for dc in SH_dcs %}
# dc is "{{ dc }}"
  {{ dc }}:
  {% for host in groups[bgpgroupname] if dc == hostvars[host].MYDC %}
    - "{{ hostvars[host].MAIN_MYADDR }}"
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

rendered output:

```
dc_route_reflectors:

# dc is "pnp"
  pnp:
      - "10.100.16.3"
      - "10.100.32.3"
  # dc is "sgs"
  sgs:
      - "10.8.0.3"
      - "10.8.16.3"
  # dc is "cst"
  cst:
      - "10.4.0.3"
      - "10.4.16.3"
  # dc is "dse"
  dse:
      - "10.200.0.3"
      - "10.200.16.3"
```

Notice how the dc is "pnp" comment is not indented as it is shown in the template, but sgs,cst and dse comments are indented by 2 spaces. All of the array lines of ip addresses are also indented. I have tried various versions of adding "-" to the "%" things as Jinja2 describes, but none have given consistent correct results.

Others must have seen this before. I'm running 2.2.1.0 on CentOS7.

Answer (score 44):

For a start, you can just remove the spaces you explicitly added in front of your statements and keep indentation only for the data:

```
dc_route_reflectors:
{% for dc in SH_dcs %}
# dc is "{{ dc }}"
  {{ dc }}:
{% for host in groups[bgpgroupname] if dc == hostvars[host].MYDC %}
    - "{{ hostvars[host].MAIN_MYADDR }}"
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to keep indentation of the statements, you can set `lstrip_blocks` option to `True` (notice: the declaration must be in the first line of the template):

```
#jinja2:lstrip_blocks: True
dc_route_reflectors:
{% for dc in SH_dcs %}
# dc is "{{ dc }}"
  {{ dc }}:
  {% for host in groups[bgpgroupname] if dc == hostvars[host].MYDC %}
    - "{{ hostvars[host].MAIN_MYADDR }}"
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Read more about [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#whitespace-control) in Jinja2.

---

Ansible runs Jinja2 with `trim_blocks` enabled and `lstrip_blocks` disabled.

All the spaces you typed into the template (outside of the statements and expressions) are thus considered a part of the output. No "extra spaces" are added.

> Notice how the dc is "pnp" comment is not indented as it is shown in the template, but sgs, cst and dse comments are indented by 2 spaces.

These two spaces are included in your template in the 7th line (before `{% endfor %}`).

> All of the array lines of ip addresses are also indented.

These spaces are defined in your template in the 5th line (in front of the `{% for host`).

Comment: That was it. When I was running it within python it must have defaulted to the opposite.Thanks.

Comment: @JerryS Please have a look at the Help Center: [do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks @techraf  for the
#jinja2:lstrip_blocks: True      What I dont understand is why Jinja as a template would mess with spaces in the first place, seems to defeat the purpose of a template

Comment: if case you need to specify multiple jinja2 config
`#jinja2: trim_blocks: True, lstrip_blocks: True`

Comment: Thanks. `#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: True` makes a lot more sense for me, generating an Envoy YAML config from a Jinja2 template with Ansible. This has bothered me quite a bit today until I finally found this answer. Almost feel like starting a bounty just to be able to give you some more rep @techraf :)